# Koszul homology of $k[x_1,...,x_n]/\mathfrak{m}^d$

Tags: commutative-algebra, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, exterior-algebra

In the book *Homology of Local Rings* of Gulliksen and Levin, it is mentioned that if we set $R=k[x_1,...,x_n]/\mathfrak{m}^d$ where $\mathfrak{m}$ is the homogeneous maximal ideal and consider the Koszul complex $K(R;x_1,...,x_n)$, "it is easy to see that"
$$Z_i(K)=\mathfrak{m}^{d-1}K_i+B_i(K)$$
for all $1\leq i\leq n$. I don't see how.

I can write down the differential $\partial_1,\partial_2$ and $\partial_n$ explicitly, so I can confirm the above statement for $i=1$ and $i=n$. In general I don't exactly know what the differentials look like.

In general all the matrices for the differentials have coefficients in $\mathfrak{m}$, hence one direction is clear. That's all I know

Is there a fast way to see this? Or is the only way to predict the differentials and compute $Z_i(K)$ and $B_i(K)$ explicitly?

Comment: Did you try doing this for small values of $d$? You say " In general I don't exactly know what the differentials look like." The differentials look *exactly* like the Koszul differentials, it just so happens that in the quotient you have more things that are zero.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff In general if I look at the component of a Koszul complex as an exterior algebra, I can see where the differentials map the basis. However I don't see the matrices representing the differentials from here. For small value of $n$ (short Koszul complexes), I can write down the matrices, sure. But I actually have not tried to predict the pattern

Comment: I assume this problem is "easy", but I guess the only way to see it is write down and compute all kernels and images?

Comment: Could you tell me if perhaps the answer below goes in line with what the authors introduce during the text? Or maybe point to where exactly in the text the claim is made? Maybe there is an easier solution.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff The authors were not discussing about this Koszul homology of this ring at all. I assume it's an advanced text, so this problem should be easy to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The differential.**
Write $R = \mathbb k[y_1,\ldots,y_n]$ for your ring, so that any $d$-fold product of $y$s is zero, and let me write $\mathcal K(R,\mathbf y)$ for the Koszul complex of $R$. This complex is generated in degree $p$ by a sum $$\mathcal K_p(R,\mathbf y) = \bigoplus_{I\subseteq [p]} R\otimes \mathbb ke_I$$
and the differential sends
$$ f\otimes e_I \longmapsto \sum_{i\in I} (-1)^i f\cdot y_i\otimes e_{I\smallsetminus i}.$$
That is, the differential is the *same* as the usual Koszul differential you know.

**Cycles and boundaries.** Now, you want to check that in this complex, we have that $Z = B + \mathfrak m^{d-1}K$.

1. One inclusion is easier than the other: of course $B\subseteq Z$, and because the differential above *always* multiplies by $y$s, then whenever you pick something in $\mathfrak m^{d-1}K$, you will land in $\mathfrak m^dK=0$. So $B+\mathfrak{m}^{d-1}K\subseteq Z$ is definitely true.
2. For the converse, suppose that you have an element $z\in Z$, that is,
   $dz=0$. You would like to write it as $dz' + \alpha$ where $\alpha\in \mathfrak{m}^{d-1}K$. We proceed by induction on $d$, noting that the
   case when $d=1$ the ring $R$ is just $\mathbb k$ and in this case the statement is obvious (all differentials are zero).

For the inductive step, consider the quotient map $R \longrightarrow R'$
where in $R'$ we quotient by $\mathfrak m^{d-1}$, which induces a map on Koszul complexes $\mathcal K(R,\mathbf y) \longrightarrow \mathcal K(R',\mathbf y')$. Given a cycle $z$ in the domain, its class $[z]$ is
a cycle in the codomain, so $[z] = [dz_1] + [z_2]$ by induction, where
$[z_2]\in \mathfrak m^{d-2}K$. This equality in the quotient complex simply
means that $z = dz_1 + z_2 + z_3$ where $z_3\in \mathfrak m^{d-1}K$, so it suffices we address the $z_2$ term.

Now $z$ is a cycle and so are $dz_1$ and $z_3$, so $dz_2=0$. Thus, we are reduced to show the following:

> *Lemma*. If $f\in \mathfrak m^{d-2}K$ is a cycle, then in fact $f\in \mathfrak m^{d-1}K+B$.

*Proof*. Since $\mathfrak m^d=0$, we can assume that when we write down $f$,
we only use elements in $R$ that are of the form $\lambda + \langle\mu,y\rangle$, that is, either constant or linear in the $y$s. But since multiplying $ \mathfrak m^{d-2}$ by a purely linear term lands in $ \mathfrak m^{d-1}$, we can simply assume that each $f_J$ is a linear combination of homogeneous elements of degree $d-2$ i.e.
$f_J = \sum_{|\alpha|=d-2} \lambda_{\alpha,J} x^{\alpha} \otimes e_J$
where $x^\alpha = x_1^{\alpha_1}\cdots x_n^{\alpha_n}$ and $|\alpha | = \sum_i \alpha_i$.

In this case, we see that $d(x^\alpha\otimes e_I) = \sum_{i\in I} (-1)^i x^{\alpha+e_i}\otimes e_I$ and are reduced to showing that

> *Lemma* If $f$ is such that each $f_I$ is a homogeneous form of degree $d-2$, then $df=0$ implies that $f\in B$.

*Proof*. This follows from Euler's formula that if $h$ is homogeneous of degree $\lambda$ then $\langle x,\nabla h\rangle = \lambda h$, which gives a contracting homotopy for the 'Koszul differential' $x\cdot h$.